# How can I replace my Xamarin NuGet packages with .NET MAUI NuGet packages in my iOS and Android projects?

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui, monogame

I have created a MonoGame iOS project and a MonoGame Android project in my solution in VS for Mac. In addition, I have a Shared Code project in my solution where I have code that is used by both platforms iOS and Android. Some time ago I installed a few Xamarin NuGet packages(for example Xamarin.Essentials) in the iOS and the Android project and everything worked fine. But now I want to try .NET MAUI instead of Xamarin.

How can I replace Xamarin with .NET MAUI? Is it only necessary to replace the Xamarin NuGet packages with .NET MAUI NuGet packages or are there any other changes that I need to make in my MonoGame iOS and Android projects?

I use VS for Mac 17.5 Preview (17.5 build 1095) and MonoGame Extension 3.8.1.303.

I have never worked with .NET MAUI before, I don't know how to migrate from Xamarin to .NET MAUI and I don't know if .NET MAUI works with the current MonoGame iOS and Android projects.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/get-started/migrate?view=net-maui-7.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link is about [how to migrate from Xamarin to .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/wiki/Migrating-from-Xamarin.Forms-(Preview)). You can check it.

And you can look at the supported frameworks tab on [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org) to see if a specific nuget handles supports your .Net 6 for your target platform.